# how do i select the last 10 records added?

Tags: sql, mysql

i am running mysql and i would like to display the last 10 records that were added. what is the select statement for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordering and limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188626/ordering-and-limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an auto-incrementing ID, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

If you don't, you'll need some criteria you can order by. An insertion date or something. The `LIMIT 10` clause is what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an autoincrementing ID you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If you have a column `added_datetime` that is set to the time of the insert then you can use that instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY added_datetime DESC
LIMIT 10
```